# What is the best similarity based sequence regression method in python for a small number of long sequences?

Tags: python, regression, sequence, similarity

I have got a set of k sequences, each with a corresponding quality value. Each sequence is a permutation of n numbers without any repetition, where n is usually larger than k.

For example consider following k=4 permutations of n=8 numbers with corresponding quality values:

(4,1,5,3,7,2,8,6), 7.63

(6,8,1,2,7,4,3,5), 4.25

(3,7,5,1,4,6,8,2), 6.58

(8,2,1,6,3,5,4,7), 4.11

Which sequence regression method, especially similarity based one, is suitable to estimate the corresponding quality value of a new sequence?

Comment: It is pretty much impossible to answer this question without extra insight into the domain of your problem (i.e. clearly defined "best" criteria). Also, my impression is that you might have better luck asking this question on stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: [stats.se] or [datascience.se] stack sites